# Ambiguous associated type when making a type alias for a numeric type

Tags: rust, traits, type-alias, associated-types

I'm writing a geometry library and am manipulating values that represent lengths.  I've written a type alias for a type that represents lengths, currently set to `f64` but could in the future be changed to `f32` or possibly other numeric types (perhaps dependent on precision and space requirements):

```rust
type Length = f64;
```

All the functions and structs in this library would then be written in terms of this type, such as this function:

```rust
fn circumference(radius: Length) -> Length {
    Length::consts::PI * radius * radius
}
```

However, the function above causes the following compiler error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     Length::consts::PI * radius * radius
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<f64 as Trait>::consts`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0223`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

but doesn't give any elaboration about the Trait I should use — presumably I need to write `<Length as Trait>::consts::PI` for some appropriately chosen `Trait`, but it doesn't tell me what this trait should be.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=33f0f45f46e2c0c0a8aa1a050835c220)

What trait should it be?

Comment: What is `Number`? Can you include the error message that came along with that help hint?

Comment: @Brian I've edited the question - I replaced `Number` with `Length` but accidentally didn't replace it all through.

Comment: The compiler's error message is wrong here, it gets confused by the type alias. The `consts` module is defined for the `std::f64` module, not the `f64` primitive type. What you need is `std::f64::consts::PI`, while `f64::consts::PI` - where `f64` is the primitive type - leads nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access [`std::f64::consts::PI`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f64/consts/constant.PI.html) through the type alias `Length`. That `PI` is a module constant belonging to the `consts` submodule of [`std::f64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f64/index.html). It isn't associated with the [`f64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.f64.html) primitive type.

To access the module constant, you'll need to either use its fully qualified name (`::std::f64::consts::PI`) or import one of the modules in its path and use a partially qualified name. For example,

```
use std::f64;
fn circumference(radius: Length) -> Length {
    f64::consts::PI * radius * radius
}

// or

use std::f64::consts as foo;
fn circumference(radius: Length) -> Length {
    foo::PI * radius * radius
}
```

To avoid intermixing `Length` with its current definition, you can always define a local constant like

```
const LENGTH_PI: Length = f64::consts::PI as Length;
```

This way, if the type of `Length` changes in the future, you only have to replace `f64::consts::PI` once.

Comment: Ohh indeed!  I didn't realise that `std::f64` isn't the same thing as `f64`.